# Is $G$ a group under those conditions?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a set and $*:G\times G \rightarrow G$ an operation with:

(i) $(G,*)$ is associative

(ii) There is a $f \in G$ with $f*a=a$ for all $a \in G$

(iii) For every $a \in G$ exists a $b \in G$ with $b*a=f$

First show that from $b*a=f$ concludes $a*b=f$

Then show that $(G,*)$ is a group.

Comment: What progress have you made? You're more likely to get help here if you show some effort on the problem.

Comment: Since (i), (ii), and (iii) are the axioms of a group, there is nothing to show.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Depends... many people assume in the axioms that the inverses and the identity are two-sided.

Comment: @Jack M: Can you give an example where dropping this *assumption* from the axioms has the effect that the structure is *not* a group anymore?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, the point of the OP is that there is no such example.  However that doesn't mean that this one-sided definition is the standard one, or that there is nothing to prove.

Comment: By (iii) $\exists c \text{ s.t. } c * b = f$. Now $c*(b*a) = c*f$ and by (i) $(c*b)*a = c*f \iff f*a = c*f \iff a = c*f$  by (ii). Now $a*b = c*f*b \iff a*b = c*b \iff a*b = f$. We can now replace (iii) by $$(iii)  \forall a \in G \exists b \text{ s.t. } a*b=b*a=f$$